# Need inputs to decide Azure Data Factory or SSIS

Tags: ssis, azure-data-factory

We are an On-prem SSIS Based DW solution. We have plans start the DW migration to Azure in early 2021.
Looking for some feedback to decide the technology .

Understand the ADF is novice as an ETL tool, not so powerful as SSIS today. ADF with limited set of activities and seems like its evolving - getting frequent updates & on areas related to data transformation as well.
current solution is build in MSSQL, SSIS built on BIML.

Can you provide insights that would assist us in making the decision.

*There are many similar questions posted couple of years ago in Stackoverflow, want to know the current status to make an decision .*

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple factors to take into consideration between ADF and SSIS:

1. Are you planning on migration to complete PaaS or have a hybrid environment of partly cloud and partly on prem/IaaS?
2. What would be your destination : Azure SQL database, Azure Mysql or Synapse?

ADF  like any Azure component is still in evolving phase but is a tool for ETL as well as ELT.
With Data flow activity in ADF and integration with Azure functions/logic apps,  you can practically achieve anything you need.

And though SSIS has a Azure package for connectivity to Storage account , ADLS etc ; there are still some restrictions w.r.t dynamic file mapping/reading from the Azure sources via SSIS.

So in case if your plan is full cloud migration, would suggest leveraging ADF over SSIS as there might be additional properties w.r.t networking that we would need to think.

Happy to discuss further based on further queries :)

Comment: This is a good answer.  I would just add that you can use legacy SSIS packages within ADF, so there would likely be no need to convert or rewrite any of your existing packages.  That's a huge boon to consider when evaluating an effort to move to ADF.  Also, I have not come across limitations within ADF which prevented me from doing anything I've also done in SSIS.  YMMV.